# Controlling Pivot Table from Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API to modify values in an Excel spreadsheet stored in OneDrive. I want to change the source range of a pivot table.  From the desktop version of Excel, this is called "Change Data Source". However, I am unable to find anyway to do this via the REST API.

There is an [MSDN Blog post](https://dev.office.com/blogs/additions-to-excel-rest-api-on-microsoft-graph) about getting information about pivot tables written nearly a year ago in December 2016.  Yet, the [latest docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel) have no mention of pivot tables.

I was able to use `GET /worksheets/{id}/pivotTables` once to get a list of pivot tables in the worksheet.  The refresh functionality (listed in the blog post) returns an error.

Is this functionality is unavailable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is included in the documentation, it just isn't surfaced in the Table of Contents (not sure why but will look into that):

- [List pivotTables](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/workbookworksheet_list_pivottables)
- [Get pivotTable](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/workbookpivottable_get)
- [Refresh](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/workbookpivottable_refresh)
- [RefreshAll](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/workbookpivottable_refreshall)

To answer your specific question, I'm afraid you cannot switch the Data Source for a given Pivot Table via the API.

*update: fixed refresh link*

Comment: Thanks Marc.  Note, the link for 'Refresh' does not work.